# find numbers divisible by 3 in csv file using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have csv file having content like below :

```
1|2|3
4|5|6
7|8|9
```

Now I would like to find the numbers which are divisible by 3 using shell scripting. 
I would like to use `awk` command for this. I am learning shell scripting. So could you please help me out to find solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 awk -F'|' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(!($i%3))print $i}' file
```

this awk one-liner shoud do.

With your example, the cmd outputs:

```
3
6
9
```

Comment: 1+ for a sensible answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -v RS='\\||\n' '$0 % 3 == 0' file
3
6
9
```

-v RS='\||\n' will set input record separator as `|` or newline, thus giving us each number in `$0`.

`!($0 % 3)` (modulo) will make sure to print only when `$0 % %3` is zero.

Comment: Personally I prefer the clarity of` `$1 % 3 == 0` (and it's the same number of characters!). Also, can't you just `print $0`, i.e. remove the action block entirely?

Comment: this may miss numbers in result, since you used `$1`, e.g, change `4` into `12` and give your cmd a try, you will see.

Comment: Thanks @Kent: for raising this point. I edited (corrected) my answer.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava: Now this answer works for each number.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk, which allows for a multi-character record separator:

```
awk -v RS='[|[:space:]]+' '$0 % 3 == 0' file
```

This sets the record separator to one or more pipes or space characters, printing each record that divides evenly by 3.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to read a CSV file into a variable:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bash-read-comma-separated-cvsfile/

Here's how to find the length of the array to which the CSVs are saved:

L=${#array[@]}

Now run a for loop like this:

```
for i in `seq 1 $L`; do
          if [ ${array[${i}]}%3 -eq 0 ] then
               echo ${array[${i}]}
          fi
done
```